# How we can link two interdependent projects in Android studio 3.6?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a sdk and a client app. The client app is using the sdk. When I build the sdk, it generates multiple aar files which I can add it in libs folder in my client project.

Now if I modify the sdk, every time I need to build the sdk code using gradlew and then add the aar in client code. This is becoming a lengthy process.

My top level build.gradle file looks like below:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to link the sdk code with client code. So the sdk changes will be automatically picked by the client code. I am using Android Studio 3.6.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `maven`, or `maven-publish` to publish to your own maven repositories, it can be local. the config like that `in build.gradle`

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        configuration = configurations.archives

        mavenDeployer {
            // the local repo address
            repository(url: uri('../repo'))

            pom.project {
                version '1.0.1'
                artifactId 'artifactId'
                groupId 'groupId'
                packaging 'aar'
                description 'version 1.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then add this repository in project build.gradle

```
 maven {
            url "file://Users.../yourProject/repo/"
        }
```

after that, you can use that as the third library. after you change it, you only need to execute it, then build the current project.

if you also want to look at the source code about SDK in the current project.
you can change to use `maven-publish` plugin.

Comment: But suppose I have multiple sub modules and I get multiple aar file for each sub modules. So where ideally I need to change? in each sub module build.gradle or the sdk's project level build.gradle? I am not sure, whether I can clarify properly.

Comment: I added the top level, build.gradle code in my main post.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee, the maven only needs config in top build.gradle. the  `uploadArchives` task you have to define in each submodule. or you can write some methods to do it in top-level build.gradle. that needs Gradle knowledge